# How to show $K = O(\frac{\log x}{\log\log x})$ in this case?

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

How to show $K = O(\frac{\log x}{\log\log x})$ when $K$ is the smallest number for the following inequality to hold:
$$
\sum_{k=K+1}^\infty \frac{(\ln2)^{k-1}}{k!} \leq \frac{1}{x}
$$
This observation can be found in this paper: [Simulating Hamiltonian dynamics with a truncated Taylor series](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.4687). It implys that we can use 
$$
k! > (k/e)^k
$$
to prove this, but I am not sure how that works.

I tried using the formula for the remainder of Taylor series, which implies
$$
\sum_{k=K+1}^\infty \frac{(\ln2)^{k-1}}{k!} \leq \frac{2(\ln 2)^K}{(K+1)!}
$$
and see if
$$
\frac{2(\ln 2)^K}{(K+1)!} \leq \frac{1}{x}
$$
$$
\Leftarrow \log(K+1)!\geq\log x + \log 2 + K \log \ln 2
$$
$$
\Leftarrow (K+1)(\log(K+1)-\log e) \geq\log x + \log 2 + K \log \ln 2
$$
holds true and gives the expected result. However, when I replace $K+1$ by $\frac{\log x}{\log\log x}$ here, it leads to
$$
\frac{\log \frac{\log x}{\log\log x}}{\log\log x} \geq 1
$$
which is not right.

Comment: If you had thought about your question, your inequality or claim is obviously wrong, because increasing $K$ decreases the sum. I've written a solution only because it is not easy to give a rigorous proof of this kind of problem the first time you encounter it. **However**, next time you must show your own work (what you think is relevant to the problem and what you have tried), because we are not a group of free homework or problem solving servants.

Answer (score 0):

**Basic inequalities**

$(n+1)^{\frac{1}{2}n} \le n! \le n^n$. [The first is proved by pairing the biggest with smallest.]

**Solution**

Given $\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \ln(2)^{k-1} \ge \frac{1}{x}$:

$\frac{1}{(m+1)!} \ln(2)^m \ge \frac{1}{x}$.

$\log((m+1)!) - m \ln(2) \le \log(x)$.

$\frac{m+1}{2} \log(m+1) - (m+1) \ln(2) \le \log(x)$.

$(m+1) ( \frac{1}{2} \log(m+1) - \ln(2) ) \le \log(x)$.

If $m \in ω(\frac{\log(x)}{\log(\log(x))})$ on some sequence of $x \to \infty$:

$\log(x) \ge ω(\frac{\log(x)}{\log(\log(x))}) \frac{1}{2}\log(ω(\frac{\log(x)}{\log(\log(x))}))$

$\ = ω(\frac{\log(x)}{\log(\log(x))}) ( \log(\log(x)) - \log(\log(\log(x))) + ω(1) )$

$\ = ω(\log(x))$.

Contradiction.

Therefore $m \in O(\frac{\log(x)}{\log(\log(x))})$ as $x \to \infty$.

Given $\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \ln(2)^{k-1} \le \frac{1}{x}$:

$\frac{1}{(m+1)!} \ln(2)^m \le \frac{1}{x}$.

$\log((m+1)!) - m \ln(2) \ge \log(x)$.

$(m+1) \log(m+1) - m \ln(2) \ge \log(x)$.

$m ( 2 \log(m+1) - \ln(2) ) \ge \log(x)$.

If $m \in o(\frac{\log(x)}{\log(\log(x))})$ on some sequence of $x \to \infty$:

$\log(x) \le o(\frac{\log(x)}{\log(\log(x))}) 2 \log(o(\frac{\log(x)}{\log(\log(x))}))$

$\ = o(\frac{\log(x)}{\log(\log(x))}) ( \log(\log(x)) - \log(\log(\log(x))) + o(1) )$

$\ = o(\log(x))$.

Contradiction.

Therefore $m \in Ω(\frac{\log(x)}{\log(\log(x))})$ as $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

When $K$ is large,
$$
\sum_{k=K+1}^\infty \frac{(\ln2)^{k-1}}{k!} \leq \frac{1}{K!} \leq \frac{e^K}{K^K}
$$
If we put $K = \frac{2\ln x}{\ln\ln x}$ in above expression,
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{e^K}{K^K} 
= e^{K-K\ln K} 
&= \exp\Big({ \frac{2\ln x}{\ln\ln x}- \frac{2\ln x}{\ln\ln x}\ln \big( \frac{2\ln x}{\ln\ln x}\big)}\Big)\\
&= \exp\Big({ \frac{2\ln x}{\ln\ln x}- \frac{2\ln x}{\ln\ln x}(\ln2 + \ln \ln x-\ln\ln\ln x})\Big)\\
&= \exp\Big(-2\ln x + \frac{(2-2\ln2)\ln x}{\ln\ln x} + \frac{2\ln x \ln\ln\ln x}{\ln\ln x}\Big)\\
&\leq \frac{1}{x} \qquad\text{when $x$ is large}.
\end{split}
$$